# How can I scale an application to fit a specific size (Linux)

Tags: xorg, debian-lenny

I have an old gui application that is hard coded to 1280x1024 and I would like to display it full screen on a 1920x1200 monitor. Are there any relatively simple ways of forcing the application to be 'stretched' to fit the screen size? It seems like X11 would have some way of handling this. I am using debian with twm.

Comment: Is tweaking the source an option? Have you tried Alt+middle click and dragging it (you never know)?

Comment: Yes, modifying the source is an option (c++ w/ motif). The application is run in a kiosk type setting, so I am looking for a way to actually start the application stretched to match the monitor resolution.

Comment: Sorry I have no C++ fu, sometimes though, the simple approach works. Try searching for 1280 in the code. You never know...